# Data not send to database because of a script which makes selecting options easier, why?

Tags: database, forms

If I use the following script I can pick by clicking in multiple menus from a form more than one option instead of pressing strg etc.

But the problem is, all elements which are selected then will not be send to my database. If I put the script off, everything works.

How can I still use the comfort which I explained in the first sentence but also that everything will be send to my database instead of an empty array.

```
<script>
 window.onmousedown = function (e) {
var el = e.target;
if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'option' && el.parentNode.hasAttribute('multiple')) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // toggle selection
    if (el.hasAttribute('selected')) el.removeAttribute('selected');
    else el.setAttribute('selected', '');

    // hack to correct buggy behavior
    var select = el.parentNode.cloneNode(true);
    el.parentNode.parentNode.replaceChild(select, el.parentNode);
}
}      
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the issue is, will your form not submit at all with the script?

Comment: Submit is working - the database get all data from every field like checkboxes, text etc. except the multiple option menus since I use this script (which makes it possible to select data in the multiple option menus by cklicking instead of select with strg etc.)

Comment: This is working fine for me, what browser are you using?  And also, maybe if you post the rest of your HTML page we can spot the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I put your code on a test page with a simple form with two `select multiple` fields, and it appears to be working correctly.  When I test this in Chrome, it submits the form fields correctly, including the `select` fields.

```html
<html>

<body>

    <form method="GET">
        <div>
            <label>Field 1</label>
            <input type="text" name="f1" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Field 2</label>
            <select name="f2" multiple="multiple">
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Field 3</label>
            <select name="f3" multiple="multiple">
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" />
        <script>
            window.onmousedown = function(e) {
                var el = e.target;
                if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'option' && el.parentNode.hasAttribute('multiple')) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    // toggle selection
                    if (el.hasAttribute('selected')) el.removeAttribute('selected');
                    else el.setAttribute('selected', '');

                    // hack to correct buggy behavior
                    var select = el.parentNode.cloneNode(true);
                    el.parentNode.parentNode.replaceChild(select, el.parentNode);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```